# How to print emoji in IDLE Python?

Tags: python

```
>>> import emoji
>>> print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbs_up_sign:'))
Python is :thumbs_up_sign:
```

Here, I am not able to print emoji and I am getting as it is in print statement. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Do you know what version you installed the module in vs. what version your idle is running for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbsup:', use_aliases=True))
```

All the aliases can be retrieved from here:
https://www.webpagefx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/

Remember to set use_aliases to True

Comment: Or `print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbs_up:'))` since maybe the problem is just `:thumbs_up_sign:`.